# What's a good way to manage web applications?

Tags: windows

I've found as I use more and more web applications like Gmail, Meebo, Basecamp, Harvest, etc. it becomes annoying that they have to exist as tabs in a browser.

Is there something that can help manage web apps beyond simply bookmarking\pinning them in the browser?

Some way to break them out into a wrapper that can start up when windows does and be moved to secondary monitors perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can make shortcuts on the desktop to Chrome with -app (or how it is) flag and URL as the parameters. It opens new chrome window, without the toolbars and tabs. Just plain old window with min,max,close. Then you can move that window to other desktops.. etc. It will not behave like a classic app though...

Also the simplest way is to pin your tab in chrome (right click on the tab, check Pin tab). It will make the tab smaller (only the icon will be left) and it cannot be closed till it's unpinned again.

EDIT: sorry if this is too much chrome-ish answer :)